# Switch SSMS from SQL Server 2005 to SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have installed SQL Server 2005 and SQL Server 2008 R2 both on my system. Now I am trying to attach a database, then it's showing a version error:

[image]

Is there any way to switch from SQL Server 2005 to 2008 R2 without uninstalling the earlier version?

Comment: How are you connecting to the database?

Comment: using SSMS... but it pointing by default to SQL server 2005..

Comment: Either upgrade your existing `SQLEXPRESS` instance to SQL Server 2008 R2, or if you have installed a new instance of SQL Server 2008 R2, use SSMS to connect to that using the instance name you gave it at installation (`.\INSTANCE`). Use the SQL Server Configuration Manager (the 2008 R2 version) if you need a list of instances.

Comment: The error message is clear - you are attempting to attach a 2008r2 database to your 2005 instance. Is that what you intended to do? I ask because your text suggests that you intended to do the opposite. You can refer to the following link for information about the internal version numbers that appear in the error message: https://jingyangli.wordpress.com/2012/03/10/six-ways-to-find-sql-server-internal-version-number/

Comment: You *can* attach a SQL Server 2005 database (version 612) to a SQL Server **2008 R2** instance (version 661) - that should work just fine. But you ***CANNOT*** under any circumstances do the opposite - attach a **newer** version of a SQL Server database to an **older** instance - that just isn't supported in any way, shape or form